# Selecting data in Pandas based on a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to return a specific value (in this example, the cost of Project2) from a dataframe column based on a condition being met. I have done some research without much luck. I did write the below code, but it only works because I happen to know `Project2` is in index position 2.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Project1', 800], ['Project2', 1000]], columns=['Project ID', 'Cost'])
print df.loc[df['Project ID'] == 'Project2'].ix[1, 'Cost']
```

Comment: does `df.loc[df['Project ID'] == 'Project2', 'Cost']` work?

Comment: that prints as a dataframe row though (meaning it prints the index). I want the actual value.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Project ID'] == 'Project2', 'Cost'].values[0]`

Comment: That solves it. Please submit as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looks for the underlying value, try

```
df.loc[df['Project ID'] == 'Project2', 'Cost'].values
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like -

```
print df[df['Project ID'] == 'Project2']['Cost']
```

The above gives the series, if you want individual values, you can loop through them -

```
for i in df[df['Project ID'] == 'Project1']['Cost']:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
print df[df['Project ID'] == 'Project2']['Cost'].values[0]
```

.values turns the series into a list and [0] selects the single element