# Pandas | selecting all rows within a group and a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As an example, if I were to have a DataFrame that looked like the following:

```
 CONTINENT     COUNTRY    POPULATION
    Europe      France         67.06
    Europe       Italy         60.36
    Europe     Denmark          5.80
      Asia       Japan        126.30
      Asia       China       1398.00
N. America      Canada         37.59
    Europe    Portugal         10.28
      Asia    S. Korea         51.71
```

How would I go about selecting the `POPULATION` figures for all the countries in `Europe`?

I tried a simple `df.loc['Europe', 'POPULATION']` but that didn't turn out correctly. Probably quite a simple solution but I can't even find the right words/phrase to Google it properly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting data in Pandas based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306519/selecting-data-in-pandas-based-on-a-condition)

Comment: Do you have any specific goal in mind ? Summation, listing ?

Comment: Just listing. Diego's solution below worked nicely.

Comment: @HenryEcker that's very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `df.loc` the first item refers to the index. You want the values of a column where other column has a certain value. You should find the indices of the places where this condition is True and then use `df.loc`.
Try the following:

```
df.loc[(df['CONTINENT'] == 'Europe'), 'POPULATION']
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Is there a way to keep the country names displayed in the resulting DataFrame?

Comment: Add `df.set_index(keys='COUNTRY', inplace=True)` before Diego's line @mlan. And you will be good to tick his answer.

Comment: Yes! Instead of selecting a single column you could select a list of columns. In your case you should do: `df.loc[(df['CONTINENT'] == 'Europe'), ['POPULATION','COUNTRY']]`

Comment: Great - thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data is in `df`, you could also try this:

```py
df[ df['CONTINENT'] == 'Europe' ]['POPULATION']
```